# Threading plus interop in program

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-c++

I have a WPF C# application, in which a certain function takes quite a long time for performing its operation.

```
int result = MyFavFunctions.mainfunction(searchquery);
```

I want to perform the calculation for this function on a separate thread, and not block the UI thread. In addition, before I get the result of this operation, I don't want to proceed with further in the function because `int result` is what I am using further.

Can this be done with threading?

In addition, I also am not sure because the functions in this mainfunction is actually exported function from a C++ dll. So, after this main function, if I use other exported functions in the dll (which are just used to fetch values), will they have the appropriate result?

Comment: Thing is when you are waiting for the int result the UI is not blocked but if that result is next thing useful to the user then no real gain.  In the callback you need to see if those exported functions are available.  Like dice said - it is easy enough to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes threading is how that would be achieved - have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx for some useful info, in particular what you want is the BackgroundWorker ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S4 ).

As to the results from the fetch functions - that is very much dependant on how the dll is implemented - if it is intended to be used that way then they should work ok - it is trivial to put together a scratch test application to verify this.